# Get the start and end point of lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography

I need to get the start and the end point of each line in a shapefile. In my case these lines represents pipelines. I need to get the start and the end points of each pipeline in an Excel sheet and to refer to the number of the line that is connected between any two points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS for Desktop then the tool to look at will be [Feature Vertices To Points (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_Vertices_To_Points/00170000003p000000/):

> Creates a feature class containing points generated from specified
>   vertices or locations of the input features.

and its BOTH_ENDS option:

> BOTH_ENDS —Two points will be created, one at the start point and
>   another at the endpoint of each input feature.

Comment: thanks for replaying I could use the feature successfully but I have a problem that is not every point is connected I have tree graph so how I can specify which point is connected to other point?

Comment: The only solution I could think about is to give the points that are connected to the same line the same objectID but I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: That sounds like it may be a new question.  If you decide to ask it then be sure to include some details like a diagram describing what you are trying to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck.